# log4j2 xml configuration - Log to file and console (with different levels)

Tags: xml, log4j, log4j2

I want to do two things:

1. Log to console with a certain log-level
2. Log to file with another log-level

Console logging seems to work just fine but the log file keeps beeing empty.

This is my log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="WARN">
  <appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/app.log" immediateFlush="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>  

  </appenders>
  <loggers>

    <logger name="filelogger" level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="MyFile"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="info">
      <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I figured it out! The `<Logger>` tag shouldn't be used in this case, see Gaurang Patel's answer for details.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="WARN">
  <appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/app.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>             
  </appenders>

  <loggers>     
    <root level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="Console" level="info"/>
      <appender-ref ref="MyFile" level="error"/>
    </root>    
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Comment: so what was the problem? posting a solution without an explanation doesn't help

Comment: @daker Hi, is it possible to specify a path where I want to save the file if I am running a war file on a tomcat server?

Comment: @Bendemann I would assume you just change the path in the `fileName` tag but I don't know.

Answer (score 20):

Although Daker had put the corrected configuration file but he didn't explain it. I would like to add explanation here. As quoted in Log4j2 Documentation [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html), usage of <Logger> tag was not required for the given requirement. Further when you should use <Logger> tag? Read below explanation form the documentation,

> Perhaps it is desired to eliminate all the TRACE output from
>   everything except com.foo.Bar. Simply changing the log level would not
>   accomplish the task. Instead, the solution is to add a new logger
>   definition to the configuration:

```
<Loggers>
  <Logger name="com.foo.Bar" level="TRACE"/> 
  <Root level="ERROR">  
    <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"> 
  </Root>
  ...
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 9):

Summary others (`@basiljames`, `@daker`, `@Jay Taylor`) answers here:

## my `log4j2.xml` Configuration

my case:

- log4j2 version: `2.13.0`
- `log4j2.xml` configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <File name="FILEOUT" fileName="your_log_filename.log" append="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] %C{2} %F%L - %m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>

    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p %F:%L - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="FILEOUT" level="debug"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="info"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

## Q: how to implement File and Console with different level ?

A: as [official doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.0/faq.html#config_sep_appender_level) also mentioned, the core part:

```xml
    <Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="FILEOUT" level="debug"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="info"/>
    </Root>
```

can achieve:

based on:

- root level is `DEBUG`

set:

- `File` level to `DEBUG`
- `Console` level to `INFO`

## Q: `@Stealth Rabbi`： so what was the problem?

A: original main problem is:

### the logger name syntax is wrong

that is `name="filelogger"` in:

```xml
    <logger name="filelogger" level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="MyFile"/>
    </logger>
```

for normally the logger name is your class name, like

```xml
    <Logger name="com.foo.bar" level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
    </Logger>
```

another possible minor problem is:

### log content level is below your file level `error`, so file created but empty

when set file level to `error`, but your log code is low level, such as

```java
logger.debug("output something");
```

that is:

**logger lever in code(`debug`)** < **file level(`error`)**

so debug content will **NOT** output to log file, log file keep empty.

## Q: `@Bendemann` is it possible to specify a path where I want to save the file if I am running a war file on a tomcat server?

A: yes. Just set the relative or absolute log file path to `File`'s `fileName`.

just like:

```xml
  <Appenders>
    <File name="FILEOUT" fileName="/your/path/your_log_filename.log" append="false">
...
```

is ok.

Answer (score 7):

`<logger name="filelogger" level="error" >`
 This should be the problem. The name of the logger usually is your package name (unless you have specifically named it `filelogger`).
Try `<logger name="com.yourpackage" level="error" additivity="true">`

Refer [Log4j2 Doc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks. It worked for the file logging but now the console output disappeared. Something wrong there as well?

Comment: Edited my answer added 'additivity="true"`

Comment: additivity is true by default in log4j2

Answer (score 1):

I use `<ThresholdFilter />` and `<AppenderRef level="">` to do this

- **Console**: output all
- **app.log**: >= info, except error
- **error.log**: >= error

> **SEE**
>
> - <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
> - <AppenderRef ref="fileLogger" level="info" />

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>      
<Configuration status="error" monitorInterval="5"> <!-- status:error mean ONLY show log4j kernel's error log in console-->
    <Properties>
        <Property name="APP_LOG_ROOT">Your log's path</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="fileLogger" fileName="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/app.log" filePattern="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <!-- Except Error -->
            <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="errorLogger" fileName="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/error.log" filePattern="${APP_LOG_ROOT}/error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace" >
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="trace" />
            <AppenderRef ref="fileLogger" level="info" />
            <AppenderRef ref="errorLogger" level="error" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```